# Go through very large directory tree with find

Tags: bash, directory, find, lazy-loading

Is `find` lazy in bash?

I'm trying to go through a directory tree to get all `*.jpg` files where there are at least 700k files in a 3 level directory tree using the following script:

```
for im in $(find $1 -name '*.jpg');
do
    echo im;

    # Do something with im... 
done
```

but is taking to long without printing anything from the `echo` and I'm sure the script works (I tested it with 50k files with 3 levels directory tree and it takes less time but at the end it prints everything).

Maybe there's a lazy version of find or something I could use to get those `echo` to show while the script is running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$()` will allocate all of `find`'s output at once. Use `while read` loop instead with process substitution (recommended with bash) or pipe:

```
while IFS= read -r im; do
    ...
done < <(exec find "$1" -name '*.jpg')
```

`exec` is my style and is optional. Since we only run one command inside the subshell summoned by process substitution, having another fork may not be necessary.

Or

```
find "$1" -name '*.jpg' | while IFS= read -r im; do
    # Unfortunately anything that happens here is already inside
    # a subshell so any variable changes would not affect the
    # parent shell.
    ...
done
```

If you have irregular filenames like filenames having a newline, use `\x00` as delimeter:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' im; do
    ...
done < <(exec find "$1" -name '*.jpg' -print0)
```

If one of your commands inside the loop reads input, it would be necessary to use another file descriptor to prevent those commands from reading input from `find`:

```
while IFS= read -ru 4 -d '' im; do
    ...
done 4< <(exec find "$1" -name '*.jpg' -print0)
```

Comment: So find is lazy, but only if you invoke it the right way. That worked thanks

Comment: Well, `find` isn't lazy, but `bash` runs it in a parallel process that it reads from, as opposed to waiting for `find` to complete before starting the loop.